# Docker Compose & Symfony on Ubuntu

Tags: php, docker, symfony

When running docker-compose up I am getting the following error:

```
Service 'web-app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c set -xe && buildDeps=" $PHP_EXTRA_BUILD_DEPS libcurl4-openssl-dev libedit-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev xz-utils " && apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && curl -fSL "http://php.net/get/$PHP_FILENAME/from/this/mirror" -o "$PHP_FILENAME" && echo "$PHP_SHA256 *$PHP_FILENAME" | sha256sum -c - && curl -fSL "http://php.net/get/$PHP_FILENAME.asc/from/this/mirror" -o "$PHP_FILENAME.asc" && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" && for key in $GPG_KEYS; do gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key"; done && gpg --batch --verify "$PHP_FILENAME.asc" "$PHP_FILENAME" && rm -r "$GNUPGHOME" "$PHP_FILENAME.asc" && mkdir -p /usr/src/php && tar -xf "$PHP_FILENAME" -C /usr/src/php --strip-components=1 && rm "$PHP_FILENAME" && cd /usr/src/php && ./configure --with-config-file-path="$PHP_INI_DIR" --with-config-file-scan-dir="$PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d" $PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS --disable-cgi --enable-mysqlnd --enable-mbstring --with-curl --with-libedit --with-openssl --with-zlib && make -j"$(nproc)" && make install && { find /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin -type f -executable -exec strip --strip-all '{}' + || true; } && make clean && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false -o APT::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant=false $buildDeps' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Any idea why and how to fix it please?

Comment: provide your docker compose file, please

Comment: This looks like an error in the Dockerfile; without seeing the Dockerfile and more of the error message it's really hard to tell what's going on.  That's a pretty long command, and one thing that might help debugging is breaking `RUN a && b && c` into separate `RUN a`, `RUN b`, `RUN c` lines so you can tell which specific step is failing.